# How to set a global variable to drive visibility of the main Navigation Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm adding a log-in screen to my angular app, and I would like to hide the main nav bar while the log-in screen is displayed. Once the log-in is passed, I need to show the main nav again. Currently the main nav is a part of the Index.html, which is the first file being served, and also is the one in which the ng-app is defined. I understand, that I can use ng-show attribute, but I do not know how to specify the condition for ng-show, which can be access and changed from within different parts of my single page app. Perhaps, a good example of using $rootScope or something similar for this purpose would really help.

Comment: you can use a variable on the current scope in your `ng-show` condition. what is the question?

Comment: I guess, the question is where and how do I set such variable. I have tried using $rootScope.mainNavVisible and then access it in the view: ng-show="$root.mainNavVisible" but I did not get anywhere with this.

Comment: I usually attach a separate controller to my nav bar, and set my variables there. if I want my navbar controller to communicate with the other controllers on the page, I use a service and inject it in all "interested" controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Every scope has a reference to $rootScope via its $root property. So anywhere in your HTML you can write

```
ng-show="$root.mainNavVisble"
```

where mainNavVisible is a property on $rootScope indicating whether the main nav should be visible or not.

Comment: I'm trying to use this approach:  in my nav bar I have <nav id="MainNav" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" ng-controller="MainPageCtrl" ng-show="$root.mainNavVisble"> In my controller: angular.module('frontEndApp').controller('MainPageCtrl', ['$scope', '$location','$rootScope',
 function($scope,$location,$rootScope) {
     $scope.go = function (path) {
         $rootScope.mainNavVisible;
          $location.path(path);
      }
  }]);  And in the login form:  <div id="signin" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="go('/home')">Sign In</div> The URL changes, but nav never show up

Comment: Looks like you are not assigning true to mainNavVisible.